# Whats happening when python objects are made via obj = object.__new__(SomeClass)

Tags: python, singleton

I am Trying to make a singleton class in python.
Which I found in one of the examples in Stackoverflow as bellow

```
class Singleton(object):
    _instance = None
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print "New called"
        if cls._instance:
            return cls._instance
        cls._instance = super(Singleton, cls).__new__(
                cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance


if __name__ == '__main__':
    s1=Singleton()
    s2=Singleton()
    if id(s1)==id(s2):
        print "Same"
    else:
        print "Different"
    print id(s1)
    print id(s2)
```

So far so good it gives me a singleton but when I am making a object with

```
s3 = object.__new__(Singleton)
```

Its giving me a completely new object.
Each time when i make a instance by **object.__new__(Singleton)** its giving me a new instance.

Its not calling the **new** method of the Singleton class for making a new object.
My question in how can I make a singleton which will work with both s1=Singleton() and s3=object.**new**(Singleton)

Comment: Well, the singleton part is all the code in `Singleton.__new__`. If you're calling `object.__new__`, you're not executing `Singleton.__new__`, hence none of the singleton related code comes into play. Not sure what you're expecting or what's unclear...!?

Comment: I am not sure how to create a singleton class which will work with any type of initialization.

Comment: You could assemble an object entirely "by hand" which looks and acts just like your `Singleton` class but executes none of its constructor code at all. In other words, you cannot possibly prevent such instantiation for all possible circumstances in a dynamic language such as Python. If someone is explicitly working around your code, you can't really stop them. But why would anyone do that? Programming is collaborative, you can't try to fight all possible code you don't want.

Comment: Yaa this may not happen in production code, but was just asking is there a way i can code to handle above scenario.

Answer (score 0):

With `object.__new__` you explicitly say, you want to use the new method of object and not the new method of Singleton. So why should anyone use this method to create a `Singleton`?

Comment: Agree but is there a way to handle above scenario.can i make a singleton class which always give me one in stance.

Answer (score 0):

`object.__new__()` is not same as `YourClass.__new__()`

When you call `YourObject`, _instance is added to your `YourObject`, and set to `None` (Remember it's static).
But, when you call `object.__new()`, there does not exist any variable in `object` called `_instance`, so when you call `YourObject`, it's assigned `None`. In short :  **your __instance logic is not checked**, when you use `__new__` of class `object`.

```
class Singleton(object):
    _instance = None
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print "New called"
        if cls._instance:
            return cls._instance
        cls._instance = super(Singleton, cls).__new__(
                cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance


if __name__ == '__main__':
    s1=object.__new__(Singleton)
    print Singleton._instance
    s2=Singleton()
    if id(s1)==id(s2):
        print "Same"
    else:
        print "Different"
    print id(s1)
    print id(s2)


I have no name!@sla-334:~/stack_o$ python trick.py 
None
New called
<__main__.Singleton object at 0xb72e3e0c>
Different
3073261036
3073261068
I have no name!@sla-334:~/stack_o$
```